# JSON property file case insensitive in Jackson

Tags: java, jackson

I have a JSON property file, which is updated by a user manually.

I am mapping it to objects, using Jackson Object mapper:

```
[ 
   {  "id":"01",
      "name":"Joe",
      "Children" : [ {"Name" : "Alex",
                       "Age" : "21"},
                     {"name" : "David",
                      "Age" : "1"}
                   ]
    },
    {  "id":"02",
       "name":"Jackson",
       "Children" : [ {"Name" : "Mercy",
                       "Age" : "10"},
                      {"name" : "Mary",
                       "Age" : "21"}
                    ]
    }
]
```

Since it is updated manually by a user, they can use any casing; mixed, upper, lower, etc. The solution I have found is, while reading the file I am converting to lower case, like this :

```
 String content = new Scanner(new File("filename")).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
```

After this I am mapping to my object using Jackson, which works.  I am using lower case member names for the mapped classes. Is it the right approach or is there any other way?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES, true);
```

This feature is in Jackson version 2.5.0 onwards.

Answer (score 1):

You can use custom PropertyNamingStrategy http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.1.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/PropertyNamingStrategy.html

Just create one and configure.

```
PropertyNamingStrategy strategy = // ... init
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(strategy);
```

You can either extend PropertyNamingStrategy class or perhaps it's better to extend PropertyNamingStrategyBase, can be easier.